# kivy scroll questions, scroll add screenmanager?

Tags: python, kivy

Thanks to your advice, we're making something.

I want to add scrolling to a template like this.

However, it is hard to find a way to get help.

How can I add scrolling functionality from here?

I tried to find it by myself, but it was not easy so I uploaded the code like this.

If the code is complicated, please advise me on how to add a scroll to the screenmanager function.

It is my first time developing as a developer. It's not really easy.

image:
[image]

python code:

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import os
import csv

# 마지막으로 누른 버튼 좌표
relative = []
# 마지막으로 누른 버튼의 id 저장
last_btn_name = ''
# 마지막으로 누른 버튼의 id와 동일한 widget들 주소값 저장
saver = []
# 마지막으로 누른 버튼의 self값 저장
remove_saver = ''
self_saver = ''
children_saver = ''
edit_saver = None
self_saver2 = None
overlap_check = None
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
# Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'fake')
Config.set('graphics', 'top', '50')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', '50')
# Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
app = App.get_running_app()
csv_counter = -1
csv_counterr = -1
department = "ENR"
Window.size = (525 , 900)
templates_path = f"{os.getenv('APPDATA')}/templates/"

with open("./Template4.5.kv", encoding='utf8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())



class CloseButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CloseButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './close_btn@2x.png'
        self.on_press = self.closeapp
    always_release =True

    def closeapp(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(App.get_running_app().stop())

class PlusButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlusButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './add_btn.png'
    always_release =True


class CheckButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CheckButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './ic_check@2x.png'
    always_release =True

class ThreeButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        global last_btn_name, relative
        super(ThreeButton, self).__init__(**kargs)
        self.source = './ic_more_vert@2x.png'
        self.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.EditDeleteButton())
    always_release = True


# 첫 번째 페이지
class FirstPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global self_saver2
        self_saver2 = self

class TemplateView(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TemplateView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.row_force_default=True
        self.row_default_height = 55
        self.orientation ='horizontal'
        Template_Label = Label(text = 'Template',
                               font_name='./NotoSans-hinted/NotoSans-Regular.ttf',
                               color=(0.43568, 0.43568, 0.43568, 1),
                               font_size=18, halign="left", valign="middle",
                               padding = (30, 0))
        Template_Label.bind(size=Template_Label.setter('text_size'))
        self.add_widget(Template_Label)
        X_Button = CloseButton(size_hint = (0.1, 0.1),
                                size_hint_x=None,
                                width=24)
        X_Button.bind(size=X_Button.setter('size'))
        self.add_widget(X_Button)
        label = Label()
        self.add_widget(label)
        label = Label(size_hint_x=None,
                                width=5)
        self.add_widget(label)
        self.add_widget(Template_Label3())

# csv 읽어와서 화면에 추가해줌
class Template_Label3(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Template_Label3, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global last_btn_name, csv_counter, self_saver, overlap_check
        self.cols = 2
        self.row_force_default = True
        self.row_default_height = 50
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        csv_counter = -1
        self_saver = self
        with open(templates_path+ department+".csv", "r", encoding="cp949", newline="") as inf, open(templates_path+department+"_temp.csv", "w", encoding="cp949", newline="") as outf:
            reader = csv.reader(inf)
            writer = csv.writer(outf)
            all = [i for i in reader]
            overlap_check = [i[0] for i in all]
            try:
                for i in all:
                    csv_counter += 1
                    self.label= Label(id = '%d' %csv_counter,
                                       text=str(i[0]),
                                       font_size = (22.5),
                                       color=(.36, .36, .36, 1),
                                       font_name = './NotoSansCJKkr-hinted/NotoSansCJKkr-Medium.otf',
                                       padding = [37, 0])

                    self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
                    self.add_widget(self.label)
                    self.three = ThreeButton(id = '%d' %csv_counter,
                                        size_hint = (0.5, 0.5),
                                    size_hint_x=None,
                                    width=15)
                    self.add_widget(self.three)
                    self.label = Label(id = '%d' %csv_counter,
                                       text=str(i[1]),
                                       font_size = (19.5),
                                       color=(.53, .53, .53, 1),
                                       font_name = './NotoSansCJKkr-hinted/NotoSansCJKkr-Regular.otf',
                                       padding = [37, -4])
                    self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
                    self.add_widget(self.label)
                    self.label = Label(id = '%d' %csv_counter, size_hint_x=None,
                                    width=10)
                    self.add_widget(self.label)
                    self.image = Image(id = '%d' %csv_counter, source = 'wall.png')
                    self.add_widget(self.image)
                    self.label = Label(id = '%d' %csv_counter, size_hint_x=None,
                                  width=10)
                    self.add_widget(self.label)
            except:
                pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(FirstPage(name = 'First_Page'))

class TemplateApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


TemplateApp().run()
```

kv code:

```
<FirstPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: "./background.png"
    TemplateView:

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: None, None

        PlusButton:
            pos_hint: {'x':3.8, 'y':0.5}
            id: plus_btn
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Add'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: In this state, I want to add a scroll function only to Template_Label3.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm probalby stating the obvious here, but have you looked at the [ScrollView widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html?highlight=scrollview)?
Make sure to only give it one child widget.